# Why does this a element have its size set to 0px x 0px when positioned using 'relative'?

Tags: html, css

I have been using [this JavaScript image annotation plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/javascript-annotation-plugin) to add annotations to a project - I managed to get it working correctly on a blank web page with just this HTML:

```
<div id="sample-image">
    <img src="img.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

And this CSS for the annotations:

```
.circle {
        border-radius: 50%/50%; 
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: black;
    }
```

This produces the correct result...

[image: example showing correct positioning]

However when I went to add this to another project, using Twitter's Boostrap and this HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200" class="span3">
          <div class="well sidebar-nav">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right" class="span9">

            <div id="sample-image">
             <img src="img.jpg"></img>
           </div>
        </div>
...
```

The elements are positioned to the top of the page because by default they have position: aboslute property like so:

```
<a class="circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Church" rel="tooltip" onmouseover="$(this).tooltip('show')" style="left: 406px; top: 247px; position: absolute;"></a>
```

Changing this to position: relative causes them to be placed correctly but their size is set to 0px x 0px according to Chrome so they are not displayed.

Any ideas why this might be?

Thanks,
Jake

Comment: compare the computed CSS of the spots between 2 sites .

Comment: Where does the width and height come from? Check in Chrome dev tools. No doubt there'll be a twitter bootstrap class adding that somewhere.

Comment: Where does the `<a>` get appended to?  Is it the `id=sample-image`?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @ExplosionPills It is the id=sample-image

Answer (score 0):

float can sometimes cause the containing objects to collapse.  Have you tried using "display: inline-block" instead?
http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

Comment: This does make Chrome report the correct size 20 x 20px but the 'dot' now appears to the right of the image. display: block makes it go beneath the image. I tried using z-index but I think I must be doing that wrong as well...

Comment: As a note, adding a float: left shows the 'dot' correctly but causes the image to shift around beneath it.